# Почему не выводится контент из таблицы MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Почему не выводится контент из таблицы MySQL?

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Таблица</h2>
    <br>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-Light">
          <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">NICKNAME:</th>
          <th scope="col">TIME:</th>
          <th scope="col">ANSWERS:</th>
          <th scope="col">INFO:</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'qwerty', 'asd', 'asdfghjkl213');
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM support_member';
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    ?>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo( "<tr>
                <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['answers'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['info'] . "</td>
            </tr>");
        } ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Файл, в котором у Вас этот код, имеет расширение `.php`? Настроен ли веб-сервер с PHP, где Вы проверяете?

Comment: Файл называется table.php проверяю на хостинге с версией PHP 7.2.32.

Comment: В Вашем коде ошибок нет, проверяйте, работает ли PHP, подключение к MySQL, наличие данных в таблице `support_member`.

Comment: А что-нибудь вообще выводится? Какие-нибудь ошибки? Мало информации

Answer (score 0):

Ответ был найден только при работе уже с форумом на этом же сервере, была версия PHP 7.4.8, которая, как я понимаю не является стабильной. Переключил на 5 версию и база данных с PHP стали работать нормально.